# Track User online, away and offline status in salesforce

Tags: apex, api, chatter, metadata-api, metadata

We have a need to track the activity of the agents using salesforce. In other words, we need to track the hours the agent has been online and away per day in salesforce. Is there any OOB functionality within salesforce for it. Can we get the details via chatter API since you see the different status in chatter.

Answer (score 3):

No, unfortunately the presence information from the online chat feature isn't available in the API.

You may want to consider using the paid [Event Monitoring](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/using_resources_event_log_files.htm) feature, which gives you access to the [EventLogFile](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.206.0.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_eventlogfile.htm) sObject. You can analyze login and logout events and can get a rough idea of idle time, assuming that you've configured sessions to [expire after some period of inactivity](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=admin_sessions.htm&type=0).